# Getting Partcover and Gallio to work on the command line error, report is Empty?

Tags: gallio, partcover

I have gotten PartCover 2.3 and Gallio 3.1 to work through the Partcover coverage browser. When I try rerunning the command on the command line I am getting a CorProfiler is turned off, and then the report is empty? I am running from Admin shell. I also had read the following [article](http://timcools.net/post/2009/09/06/Free-code-coverage-with-Gallio-and-PartCover.aspx). It says to use the /r:Local, I had to /r:IsolatedAppDomain in the broswer.

```
partcover.exe --target ..\gallio\bin\gallio.echo.exe --target-work-dir ..\.\product\RSINET.MVC.Tests\bin\debug --target-args /r:IsolatedAppDomain RSINET.MVC.Tests.dll --include +[RSINET.MVC.Tests]* --output ..\..\artifacts\RSINET.MVC.Tests.results.xml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem so I decided to take a look at PartCover's source code to see what the heck was going on, it appears the initial '+' in the include is not required, for example +[RSINET.MVC.Tests]* becomes [RSINET.MVC.Tests]*". This is inconsistent with using the settings.xml file which requires the + to be there.